# openssl errors out on GeoTrust Global CA validation but ssllabs.com marks the site as A+

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

From my docker image:

```
FROM ruby:2.7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libicu-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev curl jq poppler-utils ghostscript vim-tiny zip ffmpeg

ARG GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=wrong
ARG TOC_RELEASE=latest
ARG COMMIT_SHA=unknown

# Force UTF-8 encoding (default is POSIX/ASCII)
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -q -y --no-install-recommends \
      ca-certificates curl unzip default-jre-headless && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

If I try to connect to `reportingitc-reporter-sh-mdn.apple.com:443` I get the following error:

```
# openssl s_client -showcerts -connect reportingitc-reporter-sh-mdn.apple.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 CN = Apple IST CA 2 - G1, OU = Certification Authority, O = Apple Inc., C = US
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = reportingitc-reporter.apple.com, OU = management:idms.group.135879, O = Apple Inc., ST = California, C = US
verify return:1
```

If I validate the site with ssllabs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=reportingitc-reporter-sh-mdn.apple.com it says that the certificate is valid.

[image: ssllabs-result]

If I add the certificate manually in the docker image ssl certs it stops complaining:

```
RUN curl --max-time 300 --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --retry-max-time 900 --silent -o /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/geotrust.crt https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

I don't understand why I suddently have to do this and why ssllabs does not complain about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you've added the CA certificates package (`ca-certificates`) to your docker image, it seems that the GeoTrust Global CA root certificate isn't included in that package.

When you initially run `openssl s_client` the client downloads the certificate chain from the Apple site and finds that the last certificate is self-signed (for some reason Apple admins decided to include it as part of the chain) but as it is not in it's trust-anchor store it complains with `error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain`.

When you run your command after adding the root CA certificate, the chain downloaded from the Apple site ends in a certificate it now trusts, so no complaints.

As to why the certificate is missing - you'll need to raise that question with whoever provided you with the docker image.  It's on the current full Debian 10.4 distro and it's also on the current Alpine distro, both of which are popular with docker.  It's also, as you say, understood by SSL Labs.  If I were to guess, I'd say that the underlying base docker image is quite old.

Comment: yep you are right! the official ruby 2.7 docker image is the culprit. I don't quite understand exactly what is not up to date but when I use the bitnami provided ruby 2.7 image I don't have the problem! Thanks a lot for the info.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Debian has recently removed trust for GeoTrust Global CA. See http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/c/ca-certificates/unstable_changelog

I guess Docker images updated to the latest security updates won't trust that site.

My opinion is that trust for this CA was removed by error. I've contacted the ca-certificates package maintainer to ask about this.

Related: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=962596